# Backbone js, external templates, w/o Requirejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm trying to learn Backbone.js external templates without using Require.js like the [this](https://github.com/ccoenraets/nodecellar). But the templates doesn't show up and the div container remains empty though I found no errors. Here's the code I'm working on (I've included their paths, just in case):

`scripts/main.js`, which serves as my router

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
routes: {
    "profile": "profile",
    "view": "view",
    "else": "notFound"
},

profile: function() {
     if (!this.profileView) {
        this.profileView = new ProfileView();
     }
     $('#global-content').html(this.profileView.el);
}
});

utils.loadTpl([
    'ProfileView'],
        function() {
            app = new AppRouter();
            Backbone.history.start();
        }
);
```

`scripts/utils.js`, which loads the templates

```
window.utils = {
loadTpl: function(views, callback) {

    var deferreds = [];

    $.each(views, function(index, view) {
        if (window[view]) {
            deferreds.push($.get('templates/' + view + '.html', function(data) {
                window[view].prototype.template = _.template(data);
            }));
        } else {
            alert(view + " not found");
        }
    });

    $.when.apply(null, deferreds).done(callback);
}
};
```

`scripts/views/profile.js`, the `view` has also the same code

```
window.ProfileView = Backbone.View.extend({
initialize: function() {
    this.render();
},
render: function() {
    $(this.el).html(this.template);
    return this;
}
});
```

then I placed the templates in the same parent folder as `scripts/`

I've tried running them in the console and they work just fine, if that helps

`profileView = new ProfileView()render();`

`profileView.el` --which gives me the profile.html template correctly

I've read about Require.js but I want to do this without it.

thanks

Comment: Backbone recommends http://documentcloud.github.io/jammit/

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I'm using `yeoman` and I just want to do it based on the github repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything works well.

The problem is within the `index.html`,
I used `<div id='global-container'>`
but in `main.js` I called for `#global-content`

Answer (score 1):

Please check this line

```
$(this.el).html(this.template);
```

it should be replaced with

```
$(this.el).html(this.template());
```

but if you say that this works I think it may be other problem

```
profileView = new ProfileView().render();
console.log(profileView.el);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, though it didn't solved my question, I found the answer because of it

Comment: Will you post the answer ?

Comment: sorry about that, I only noticed it when I place your code(the last part) to replace the `profile:function(){..}` in `main.js` because it certainly outputs the template in the console. thanks!